# Why does 'append' not work as expected in my Python code?

Tags: python, append

I downloaded Google's Python exercises and this is one of the questions:

> Given a list of strings, return the count of the number of strings
>   where the string length is 2 or more and the first and last chars of
>   the string are the same

My answer to this is given below:

```
def match_ends(words):
  a=[]
  for word in words:
    if len(word)>=2 and word[0]==word[-1]:
      a=a.append(word)
    return len(a)
```

However, for this list:

```
words=['aba', 'xyz', 'aa', 'x', 'bbb']
```

It just returns "1". I don't understand why `append` did not add all strings that match with if turn.

This is Google's solution:

```
def match_ends(words):
  count = 0
  for word in words:
    if len(word) >= 2 and word[0] == word[-1]:
      count = count + 1
  return count
```

Comment: `append` is done *in-place*. Drop the assignment.

Comment: Your `return` is indented the wrong way, it should be more to the left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues here:

- an indentation issue:

```
def match_ends(words):
  a=[]
  for word in words:
    if len(word)>=2 and word[0]==word[-1]:
      a=a.append(word)
    return len(a)
```

The `return` statement is placed **inside the `for` loop**, meaning that after only one iteration, you will return an answer (either zero or one). So you can fix this like:

```
def match_ends(words):
  a=[]
  for word in words:
    if len(word)>=2 and word[0]==word[-1]:
      a=a.append(word)
  return len(a)
```

- furthermore you assign the result of `a.append(word)` to `a`. [`.append`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) however returns `None` (actually `.append` does not return anything, so Python let it automatically return `None`), so the next iteration, `a` is not a `list` anymore and the program would crash. So replace `a = a.append(word)` with `a.append(word)`:

```
def match_ends(words):
  a=[]
  for word in words:
    if len(word)>=2 and word[0]==word[-1]:
      a.append(word)
  return len(a)
```

Now your program will work. Nevertheless it **is useless to store all the matched words** because you are only interested in counting them. You better use a counter and increment the counter if you found a match because this requires no additional memory. **Google's answer is thus more efficient**.

Answer (score 1):

Indent your return statement like this:

```
for word in words:
    if len(word)>=2 and word[0]==word[-1]:
        a.append(word)
return len(a)
```

When you placed it in the level of `if` it prints the length of the list `a` that now contains ['a'] as 1 (validated true for the first word that it found to have first and last letter to be the same) and exits since it is a `return` statement. The loop doesn't validate any other word in your list `words`.

Edited the answer as I didn't notice the assignment. `append` function doesn't need an assignment. Thank you @Willem

Comment: Mind this does not fully solve the problem: since `a = a.append(word)`, after one iteration, `a` will be set to `None` and thus the program will crash in the second iteration.

Comment: It will not *return* `None`, `a` will *become* `None` after the `if` statement succeeds.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah got the mistake I overlooked. Thank you. Changed the answer accordingly